# Get method name as string or symbol in ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

I have an array of methods like this:

```
def method1
  1
end

def method2
  2
end

m = [method1, method2]
```

I want to print the method names and values that are in `m` so that I get an output like:

```
method1: 1
method2: 2
```

Is it possible to get the name of a defined method as string or symbol? How can I get a method name as string or symbol?

Comment: This is clearly an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). There are _no circumstances_ under which you might need this. Also, your code is invalid and won’t pass ruby parser.

Comment: You might think you need it, but in reality, you are not. That is why I said it’s an _XY Problem_.

Comment: You don't have an "array of methods". `m = [method1, method2]` results in `[1, 2]` because the methods are invoked and the results are being stored in the array. The method name information is not retained, you just have the values.

Comment: @Stefan well okay, then it just doesn't work as I expected. thanks!

Comment: FWIW: `ms = methods; def m; 42; end; methods - ms #⇒ [:m]`. And: `method((methods - ms).first).() #⇒ 42`.

Comment: @LPrc other languages distinguish between `foo()` (result of invoking method foo) and `foo` (method foo itself). In Ruby, both invoke the method and return its result. You _could_ get a _method object_ via `m = method(:foo)` and invoke it via `m.call` and find its name via `m.name` but that's quite unidiomatic. Methods aren't first class citizens in Ruby, the `Method` class is more like a wrapper around the actual method. We usually pass the method's name as a symbol in that case (as shown in [spickermann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51668345/477037)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this the line `m = [ method1, method2 ]` the variable `m` has no information anymore about the methods that were called to assign `[1, 2]` to `m`.

Therefore, instead of storing the values that were returned by the methods I purpose to just store the *method names* in the array and use `public_send` to call the method when you need both their names and their return values:

```
m = [:method1, :method2]

def method1
  1
end

def method2
  2
end

m.each { |name| puts "#{name}: #{public_send(name)}" }
# => method1: 1
#    method2: 2
```

Or you might want to use a hash to store the method names and the returned values right away when assigning tehm to `m`:

```
m = { method1: method1, method2: method2 }
m.each { |name, value| puts "#{name}, #{value}" }
```

Comment: It's more common to use symbols, i.e. `m = [:method1, :method2]`

Comment: Also `%i[method1 method2]` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa `%i` is a nice language construct, but unfortunately it breaks the ability to easily search for symbols in the code.

Comment: @Stefan eh. I never met this particular issue, but here you go: `/%i\[[^\]]*\b#{symbol}\b/`. Welcome.